# Print keys from plist based on values?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How do i iterate and print the keys of a plist based on given values?

Example:

```
; plist
(defun my-list() (list :a "hi" :b "no" :c "go"))

; from that list i want to iterate and print out keys based on values like:
for each x in ("hi" "go") print x

; hoping for:
ac
```

Im new to lisp - thank you :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like

```
(loop for (key value) on my-list by #'cddr
      when (member value '("hi" "go") :test #'equal)
      do (princ key))
```

The first line moves a pattern over the list.

Answer (score 4):

you can use loop macro:

```
(loop
   for (key value . rest) on list
   by #'cddr
   when (find value '("foo" "bar") :test #'string=)
   do (princ key))
```